# Generating unsigned APK with react native cause error: verifyReleaseResources'

Tags: android, react-native

Im trying to generate a unsigned apk using react native, but it won't generate and I am getting some error. I did check the stacktrace, but I cant figure out what went wrong. Is there any similar issue like mine? I've been stuck here for  days.

I installed several modules such as: `react-native-router-flux`, `react-native-sqlite-storage`, `react-native-print`

Below is the stacktrace:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-print:verifyReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':react-native-print:verifyReleaseResources'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:76)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
        ... 29 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:809)
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:797)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask.linkResources(VerifyLibraryResourcesTask.java:243)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask.compileAndVerifyResources(VerifyLibraryResourcesTask.java:140)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask.doFullTaskAction(VerifyLibraryResourcesTask.java:96)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        ... 39 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\bayuw\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\bayuw\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar -M \\?\C:\reactnative\training01\node_modules\react-native-print\android\build\intermediates\manifests\aapt\release\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\reactnative\training01\node_modules\react-native-print\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release --non-constant-id -0 apk --no-version-vectors}
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractAapt.link(AbstractAapt.java:34)
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:807)
        ... 45 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\bayuw\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\bayuw\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar -M \\?\C:\reactnative\training01\node_modules\react-native-print\android\build\intermediates\manifests\aapt\release\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\reactnative\training01\node_modules\react-native-print\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release --non-constant-id -0 apk --no-version-vectors}
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.buildProcessException(GradleProcessResult.java:73)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:48)
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:78)
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:74)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1237)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:399)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:911)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:822)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:664)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:48)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessExecutor$1.run(GradleProcessExecutor.java:58)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\bayuw\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:382)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:46)
        ... 9 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 54s
104 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 101 up-to-date
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false


def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.training01"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-print')
    compile project(':react-native-camera')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile project(':react-native-sqlite-storage')
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

Comment: Please add `build.gradle` from app directory

Comment: its added now, hope that help

Comment: @baycisk what is your react native version ?

Comment: Try to use  targetSdkVersion 27 and try again.

Comment: Are you using gradle plugin 3+?

Comment: my react native version is 55.4, using gradle 3+, yes

Comment: Maybe the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78189195/2967645)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close all running terminal windows first. 
Try to remove the library using `npm uninstall react-native-print --save` 
Unlink the library using `npm unlink react-native-print`
After that re-install the library using `npm install react-native-print --save` and link using `npm link react-native-print` 
Delete **build** from **android/build** folder. 
Finally run this script command from your project directory to get apk

```
mkdir -p android/app/src/main/assets && rm -rf android/app/build && react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

Comment: It still giving same error, i did try to remove it, but no luck

Comment: @baycisk try to change targetSdkVersion to 27 in your build.gradle file

Comment: this help me successfully generated unsigned apk, but i cannot install it on device, it just saying not installed, no further info. so still not solve the problem

Comment: @baycisk make sure you have remove Google Play Protect. Remove all ticks from Google Play Protect. It can be found in Google Play Store

Comment: where is that option? i didnt relesae signed apk, the unsigned one

Comment: @baycisk Yes of course. You need to go Google Play Store settings and disable Google Play Protect and try to reinstall the apk on the device

Comment: still not working, i dont think that the issue, i even try to install new rn by react-native init projectname, then gradlew assembleRelease, this new file cannot be use also, what is wrong?

Comment: @baycisk Try to get output apk by giving above mentioned code script on the answer

Comment: After i tried severak time, now its working. thanks!

Comment: @baycisk nice to hear that !!! If your problem solved guve thumbs up for this answer

Answer (score 2):

Steps to create unsigned apk : 
Go to project directory

1) mkdir android/app/src/main/assets

2) react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

3) cd android

4) ./gradlew assembleDebug

you will get the apk inside android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk