# Getting "verifyReleaseResources" error after upgrading React Native

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, react-native

I'm trying to upgrade an application to React Native 0.57.1. I think I've followed all the steps, upgraded all the right files, yet I'm still getting an error that I cannot understand:

```
:react-native-document-picker:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-document-picker:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-document-picker:verifyReleaseResourcesC:\Users\USERNAME\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\b3b5480809d523e6f8b8de92faafbcda\res\values-v26\values-v26.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.

C:\Users\USERNAME\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\b3b5480809d523e6f8b8de92faafbcda\res\values-v26\values-v26.xml:13:5-16:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.

C:\Users\USERNAME\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\b3b5480809d523e6f8b8de92faafbcda\res\values-v26\values-v26.xml:17:5-93: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster' not found.

C:\Users\USERNAME\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\b3b5480809d523e6f8b8de92faafbcda\res\values\values.xml:251:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.

C:\Users\USERNAME\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\b3b5480809d523e6f8b8de92faafbcda\res\values\values.xml:251:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/font not found.

C:\Users\USERNAME\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\b3b5480809d523e6f8b8de92faafbcda\res\values\values.xml:251:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found.


error: failed linking references.
:react-native-document-picker:verifyReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-document-picker:verifyReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

I can't really make sense of these errors, any idea what they mean? How can I find out how to fix this?

I've tried various things, including deleting the .cache directory, changing the gradle version but nothing seems to help. Any idea?

Comment: I just spent an entire day on this error :-( ugh! Finally found the this post and read the explanation in @hadi-mir 's answer - made sense, implemented it, BAM, good to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You need to add following code in your project's android/build.gradle:

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 27
                buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @LukeWilliams It's due a grade dependency mismatch. You're fixing the mismatch with that code. The `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion` should match what you have in your `android/build.gradle`

Comment: Don't make the same mistake as me and add to your  `android/app/build.gradle`. -20minutes.

Comment: This same config might not work for everyone. You should change the value of `compiledSdkVersion` & `buildToolsVersion` according to your project's value. For me, it was 28 and 28.0.3 respectively.

Answer (score 56):

For me, what fixed the issue was prefixing with **app**

```
./gradlew app:assembleRelease
```

Comment: though the build works but app later breaks when installed

Answer (score 12):

**Reason for the error:**

You have installed  *react-native-document-picker* as a dependency, And the reason for this error is that the configurations of your `android/app/build.gradle` and   `node_modules/react-native-document-picker/android/build.gradle` mismatch.

**Solution**

1. Navigate to `node_modules/react-native-document-picker/android/build.gradle`
2. Edit and keep the `compileSdkVersion` `buildToolsVersion` `minSdkVersion` 
   `targetSdkVersion` same as you have in `android/app/build.gradle`
3. Sync the project again.
4. Run `./gradlew assembleRelease` from the terminal.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation although I'd rather not edit package files directly, but it's good to know why it happens.

Comment: Sure thing, Happy to help

Comment: So every time you clone the project and do `npm install` you have to do this? I don't think that's a good solution.

Comment: @FrancoisBeaulieu well this issue is caused by the external npm dependency. In this particular example, the "react-native-document-picker".
I would make a pull request, or clone the repo and update to my needs if I was in the same situation.

Comment: @Rotarepmi exactly, forks the project or makes a pull request is a good solution.

Comment: Thanks, could solved similar error with react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer

Comment: Thanks, Found similar solution elsewhere also but, Your explanation helped quite a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Had another reason for this issue, I had previously modified minSdkVersion.
All you need to do is to remove /node_modules/ folder, /android/build and /android/app/build folders, re npm install and perform ./gradlew assembleRelease again.

Answer (score 0):

The command `cd android && ./gradlew app:assembleRelease` do the magic.

I've found a github link where a command help in almost every type of **verifyReleaseResource** errors. Ref: https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config/issues/330#issuecomment-494915023

Answer (score 0):

**Reason for the error:**

In my case, I had installed  `react-native-thermal-receipt-printer` as a dependency, And the reason for this error is that the configurations of your `android/build.gradle` and   `node_modules/react-native-thermal-receipt-printer/android/build.gradle` mismatch.

**Solution**

1. Navigate to `node_modules/react-native-thermal-receipt-printer/android/build.gradle`
2. Edit and keep the `compileSdkVersion` `buildToolsVersion` `minSdkVersion`   `targetSdkVersion` same as you have in `android/build.gradle`
3. Save it and change dir `cd android`.
4. Run `./gradlew clean`
5. Run `./gradlew assembleRelease`

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting this error by running something like `react-native run-android --deviceId DEVICE_ID_HERE`, there's a bug on React-Native where it tries to build the app for a specific device (with `--deviceId` as an argument) using this command `./gradlew build -X lint` instead of this one `./gradlew app:build -X lint`.

It fails with this error because most of the React-Native apps are multi-module on the Android side and when you don't specify the app name it should build, Gradle tries to guess which one is the root one, thus guessing wrongly and throwing this error.

In order to fix this issue, you may want to patch this issue with `yarn patch` or `npm patch-package` commands, the result is something like the following:

```
diff --git a/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js b/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js
index 1fb363dc18e5719a592014e11e55e3348ce54a28..046585ede2e07a4716d6e9e2a44c2b0d64255103 100644
--- a/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js
+++ b/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js
@@ -159,7 +159,7 @@ function runOnSpecificDevice(args, gradlew, packageName, adbPath, androidProject
 
   if (devices.length > 0 && deviceId) {
     if (devices.indexOf(deviceId) !== -1) {
-      buildApk(gradlew, androidProject.sourceDir);
+      buildApk(gradlew, args.appFolder || androidProject.appName, androidProject.sourceDir);
       installAndLaunchOnDevice(args, deviceId, packageName, adbPath, androidProject);
     } else {
       _cliTools().logger.error(`Could not find device with the id: "${deviceId}". Please choose one of the following:`, ...devices);
@@ -169,10 +169,10 @@ function runOnSpecificDevice(args, gradlew, packageName, adbPath, androidProject
   }
 }
 
-function buildApk(gradlew, sourceDir) {
+function buildApk(gradlew, appName, sourceDir) {
   try {
     // using '-x lint' in order to ignore linting errors while building the apk
-    const gradleArgs = ['build', '-x', 'lint'];
+    const gradleArgs = [`${appName}:build`, '-x', 'lint'];
 
     _cliTools().logger.info('Building the app...');
```