# Execution failed for task ':react-native-youtube:verifyReleaseResources'

Tags: android, ios, react-native

While making build of react native app I get the following error.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-youtube:verifyReleaseResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

And after this the build is failed.Why this came and what is the possible solution for this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "verifyReleaseResources" error after upgrading React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52613089/getting-verifyreleaseresources-error-after-upgrading-react-native)

Answer (score 7):

**Reason for the error:**

You have installed  *react-native-youtube* as a dependency, And the reason for this error is that the configurations of your `android/app/build.gradle` and   `node_modules/react-native-youtube/android/build.gradle` mismatch.

**Solution**

1. Navigate to `node_modules/react-native-youtube/android/build.gradle`
2. Edit and keep the `compileSdkVersion` `buildToolsVersion` `minSdkVersion` 
   `targetSdkVersion` same as you have in `android/app/build.gradle`
3. Sync the project again.
4. Run `./gradlew assembleRelease` from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `node_modules/react-native-youtube/android/build.gradle` file like this:
https://github.com/hwjfordev/react-native-youtube/commit/606401aa236e94394736fcc43ce9a4e29bf6a129