# How to build 64 and also 32 bit APK with React Native

Tags: android, react-native, 64-bit

I have upgraded my app to react-native 0.59.x in order gain 64 bit compatibility for the upcoming cutoff from google:

> apps using native code must provide a 64-bit version (in addition to the 32-bit version)
>
> -- *https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html*

Notice that we must provide *both* version. I expect to do this by assembling two separate APKs. How is this accomplished?

Currently, I run `./gradlew assembleRelease` and get one APK in my directory `app/build/outputs/apk/release`

UPDATE: If the answer is that React Native is intended to output a single APK which contains all 32bit and 64bit versions, then that surely answers my question as well. My expectations could certainly be off.

Answer (score 0):

From the official [document](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit)

> If your app uses only code written in the Java programming language or
> Kotlin, including any libraries or SDKs, your app is already ready for
> 64-bit devices. If your app uses any native code, or you are unsure if
> it does, you will need to assess your app and take action.

For the ARM architecture, the 32-bit libraries are located in armeabi-v7a. The 64-bit equivalent is arm64-v8a.

For the x86 architecture, look for x86 for 32-bit and x86_64 for 64-bit.

Which is covered in Universal APK. That is what you are producing, so don't need to worry!

Still, have doubt then put your apk on apk analyzer of Android Studio and check out if it has or not the library.

Comment: He's using ReactNative, which has a variety of C libraries that need to be in the correct ABIs (including the Javascript interpreter that the code runs on).  I would suspect that RN will set it up for him properly if he uses the right toolchain, but this doesn't answer his question-  its not a matter of just Java/Kotlin, its a matter of native C code.

Comment: But react native covers the 64 bit versions. I checked it by running it

Comment: @MasukHelalAnik If I understand correctly, you're saying that react-native will product one APK containing 32 bit and 64 bit versions of each library? This is what you're calling Universal APK?

Comment: @MasukHelalAnik I have no idea if RN provides 64 bit and 32 bit libraries.  My guess is that if RN doesn't provide both now, it will soon.  But your answer is about apps written in pure Java and Kotlin, not about how to ensure all the right react native libraries are there.  At best its an "even a broken clock" type answer-  right answer with totally wrong reasoning.

Comment: @GabeSechan: "I would suspect that RN will set it up for him properly if he uses the right toolchain" ... I'm sorry I don't understand. Care to elaborate? :D

Comment: check this out http://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2019/03/12/releasing-react-native-059. the new version supports 64 bit

Comment: "Updated JSC means performance gains and 64-bit support on Android" this is the official announcement. And mostly anyone can sure by putting the apk on apk analyzer and see it has the 64 bit libary or not!

Comment: This  from their repo https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/18754

Comment: I checked it out RN's Universal apk works for 64-bit version too. @GabeSechan it will be really helpful for me if I am wrong

Comment: @MasukHelalAnik I have a separate question going for _how_ to check whether the libraries within an APK are actually 64bit or not. You can get some upvotes there if you want to explain there as well :) If I learn how to verify some libraries are in fact 64 bit or 32 bit, then I can verify if your answer to this question is also right, and upvote you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55765248/how-to-check-react-native-libraries-for-64-bit-compatibility

Comment: @MasukHelalAnik "Yes, is that wrong?"  ... I don't know! That is why I'm asking, haha. My dilemma is that I don't know how to confirm whether these files are actually 64bit or not. I'm asking that in a separate question on SO, since it actually is a different question.

Comment: @lance.dolan https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2814. Check out this issue, read the discussions, according to this if your any library is not 64 bit compatible it won't be compiled into 64 bit. And build won't be happening! If you have that kind of problem. Then you can detect which library is compatible or not!

Comment: Upvoting because it appears you are absolutely correct - the single APK being output _is_ for 32 and 64. Do you mind if I edit your answer so that it's more clear to me, and then might be more useable to posterity?

Comment: Not at all. Go ahead