# Android verifyReleaseResources fails, resource not found

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

`verifyReleaseResources` keeps failing for my android assembleRelease build.

A description of my `react-native` build

```bash
System:
    OS: macOS 12.6
    CPU: (10) x64 Apple M1 Max
    Memory: 22.59 MB / 32.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.19.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.1/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.18 - ~/github/snackpass/snackpass-client/node_modules/.bin/yarn
    npm: 8.19.2 - /opt/homebrew/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2022.10.31.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 21.4, iOS 15.5, macOS 12.3, tvOS 15.4, watchOS 8.5
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Dolphin 2021.3.1 Patch 1 Dolphin 2021.3.1 Patch 1
    Xcode: 13.4.1/13F100 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.11 - /Users/alitamoore/.jenv/shims/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1 
    react-native: ^0.64.4 => 0.64.4 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

Here’re some sample errors I got

(Warning/Error) *Argfile not found*

```bash
Argfile not found: /Users/alitamoore/Library/Application Support/kotlin/daemon/promotedai_react-native-metrics_release
```

(error) *Incompatible kotlin version*

```bash
/Users/alitamoore/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/39d9fb5957939f0b72af860a8de1b4e0/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
/Users/alitamoore/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/556bb75edc66f947ffbea3dd348ad797/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-common-1.6.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
/Users/alitamoore/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/572b2229271f904a5c21007cf91f4994/transformed/jetified-react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-release-api.jar!/META-INF/ReactAndroid_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
/Users/alitamoore/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/687b7f7119d3db63f03c30ceb978b8e7/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
/Users/alitamoore/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b89184fd2243c0ba9c21f04aac02ee1a/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
```

If I force the kotlin version the dependency to 1.6.0 then I get another error
(Error) *failed linking file resources*

```bash
Execution failed for task ':promotedai_react-native-metrics:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > 1 exception was raised by workers:
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
     AAPT: /Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client/node_modules/@promotedai/react-native-metrics/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/layout/autofill_inline_suggestion.xml:18: error: resource attr/autofillInlineSuggestionChip (aka ai.promoted:attr/autofillInlineSuggestionChip) not found.
     /Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client/node_modules/@promotedai/react-native-metrics/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/layout/autofill_inline_suggestion.xml:25: error: resource attr/autofillInlineSuggestionStartIconStyle (aka ai.promoted:attr/autofillInlineSuggestionStartIconStyle) not found.
     /Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client/node_modules/@promotedai/react-native-metrics/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/layout/autofill_inline_suggestion.xml:32: error: resource attr/autofillInlineSuggestionTitle (aka ai.promoted:attr/autofillInlineSuggestionTitle) not found.
     /Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client/node_modules/@promotedai/react-native-metrics/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/layout/autofill_inline_suggestion.xml:41: error: resource attr/autofillInlineSuggestionSubtitle (aka ai.promoted:attr/autofillInlineSuggestionSubtitle) not found.
     /Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client/node_modules/@promotedai/react-native-metrics/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/layout/autofill_inline_suggestion.xml:50: error: resource attr/autofillInlineSuggestionEndIconStyle (aka ai.promoted:attr/autofillInlineSuggestionEndIconStyle) not found.
     error: failed linking file resources.
```

This error is also unpredictable, sometimes after clearing cache it passes the build.

Comment: You may want to try [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78189195/2967645)

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know why this happens, exactly. But I do know that removing the offending linked packages (note that links only apply RN < 0.69.0) from android/settings.gradle fixes it.
e.g. remove these lines (in the example given)

```java
include ':@promotedai_react-native-metrics'
project(':@promotedai_react-native-metrics').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@promotedai/react-native-metrics/android')
```

---

While I was debugging this, I also found some useful solutions to the errors mentioned. They may be useful:

**Argfile not found**

Try

```bash
cd android
./gradlew clean
```

**Incompatible Kotlin Version**

If you notice in the above errors it says `The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15` but `1.1.15` is not a valid version of Kotlin. So if you override that with a valid version it’ll fix the issue. Try applying it project wide first (android/build.gradle)

```java
buildScript {
  ext {
    kotlinVersion = “1.6.0”
  }
}
```

If that has issues, then you can override it directly in the dependency and then save those changes with `patch-package`

**failed linking file resources**

In some cases you may see `error: resource android:attr/lStar not found`. In that case, see [Saurabh’s suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69050529/13752922) or [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GDAq4ZuNTW4) I found useful.